# Small initialization problem

Tags: c#

I need a little help in the below initialization. What's wrong I'm doing below.

```
DateTimeOffset? dateTimeFrom, dateTimeTo = null;
```

I'm getting an error "Use of Unassigned local variable dateTimeFrom".

Also is there any other way to convert nullable DateTime to nullable DateTimeOffset.

What currently I'm doing is:

```
DateTimeOffset? dateTimeFrom, dateTimeTo = null;
            if (ViewModel.FromDate.HasValue)
                dateTimeFrom = new DateTimeOffset(ViewModel.FromDate.Value);
            if (ViewModel.ToDate.HasValue)
                dateTimeTo = new DateTimeOffset(ViewModel.ToDate.Value);
```

But I think there is a better and elegant way to do the above steps also.

Comment: dateTimeFrom should be defined in C# before it's use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTimeOffset? dateTimeFrom = ViewModel.FromDate.HasValue ? new DateTimeOffset(ViewModel.FromDate.Value) : null;

DateTimeOffset? dateTimeTo = ViewModel.ToDate.HasValue ? new DateTimeOffset(ViewModel.FromDate.Value) : null;
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't initialised both variables, only the second one.

See [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/multiple-local-variable) for more info.

And try:

```
DateTimeOffset? dateTimeFrom = null, dateTimeTo = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

`DateTimeOffset? dateTimeFrom, dateTimeTo = null;` initializes the second variable to null leaving the first one uninitialized.

Try

```
DateTimeOffset? dateTimeFrom = null, dateTimeTo = null;
```

or

```
DateTimeOffset? dateTimeFrom = null;
DateTimeOffset? dateTimeTo = null;
```